# How to insert Dynamic SQL Result INTO Temporary Table

Tags: sql-server, database, stored-procedures, temp-tables

I implement some code:

```
BEGIN

DECLARE 
         @SQL  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
         @TempTable AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @SQL = 'SELECT * from Employee where Instance_ID = 1';


BEGIN 

CREATE TABLE ##tempResults (SQL NVARCHAR(4000))
INSERT INTO ##tempResults EXEC @SQL;

SET @TempTable= 'select * from #tempResults ORDER BY CASE WHEN ' + @index+ ' =1 THEN [First Name] END DESC '+ ',' + ' CASE WHEN ' + @index + '=2 THEN [Last name] END DESC'

END 

EXEC sp_executesql @TempTable; 

END
```

I want to insert the dynamic results into temp table but I can't execute statement and get error. Please advice me for how should I need to do ?

As the error shown:

> "Msg 203 is not a valid identifier."

Answer (score 0):

You should use `EXEC(@SQL)` See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql)

It is advisable to switch to `exec sp_executesql @SQL`, it gives you parameterization and helps agains sql injection. Especially since you already use this later on in your query (it's never a good idea to use different methods to accomplish the same thing). See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql)